# Можно ли в VS Code сделать автоматическое удаление exe-файла после того, как отработала программа на C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Я занимаюсь олимпиадным программированием на C++ и на каждую задачу создаю отдельный файл, например, 1.cpp для первой задачи, 2.cpp для второй и т. д.

Когда я запускаю файл с помощью Code Runner, автоматически создается файл 1.exe (или 2.exe, в зависимости от имени файла cpp) в той же папке. После того, как программа отработала, этот exeшник остается.

В итоге, если я решаю олимпиаду, где 20 задач, у меня в итоге в папке получается 20 файлов *.cpp и 20 файлов *.exe.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы exeшник автоматически удалялся сразу, как только программа отработает?

Или, например, сделать так, чтобы при запуске Code Runner, создавался не exeшник в текущей папке с таким же именем, как *.cpp, а файл a.exe (который бы создавался в корневой папке), который автоматически создается при отладке любого файла, который находится в любой папке.

Comment: Так правила напишите и все) есть же там task'и

Comment: @Andrey а можете помочь с этим?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks Прочитайте это, дальше подумайте просто о том как сделать то, что Вы хотите

Comment: @Andrey благодарю

Comment: *.exe файлы можно прятать (они будут существовать, но не будут отображаться в vs code), ещё можно code runner перенастроить и он всегда будет создавать файл с одним именем

Comment: @eXit а как его перенастроить?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner посмотрите на executorMap, там можно сказать компилятору какой файл создавать

Comment: @eXit вот, что стоит в "executorMap" - "code-runner.executorMap": "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"

Что здесь нужно написать, чтобы при запуске Code Runner создавался файл a.exe в корневой папке открытой в VS Code?

Comment: например, "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o a.exe && a.exe"

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой как и у вас, как пофиксили?